# How to construct a color map in seaborn from a list of RGB colors?

Tags: python, colors, seaborn

I would like to start with a list of RGB colors, and from them construct a color map I can use in `seaborn` plots.  I have found several instructions on how to change the default color map, but that's not what I'm looking for.  I would like to construct a color map that I can use in the `cmap` argument of, for instance, the `kdeplot` command.

Comment: Did you try anything? I suppose any solution you find after searching for something like "matplotlib custom colormap" would at least get you started. If you then find a problem, asking about that specific problem would make it easier to help.

Comment: https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.colors.ListedColormap.html

Comment: Have you had a chance to try the solution in my answer?

Comment: @WilliamMiller Sorry, I'm on a different project now.  I hope I will get the chance to give it a try on my own time soon.  Thanks very much.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Constructing a [`matplotlib.colors.ListedColormap`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.colors.ListedColormap.html#matplotlib.colors.ListedColormap) from a list of colors is fairly trivial. Here is an example using the first 4 colors in the tableau 20 color palette -

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap
from matplotlib import cm

# Tableau 20 color palette for demonstration
colors = [(31, 119, 180), (174, 199, 232), (255, 127, 14), (255, 187, 120)]
# Conversion to [0.0 - 1.0] from [0.0 - 255.0]
colors = [(e[0] / 255.0, e[1] / 255.0, e[2] / 255.0) for e in colors]

cmap = ListedColormap(colors)

a = np.outer(np.linspace(0, 1, 20), np.linspace(0, 1, 20))
im = plt.imshow(a, cmap=cmap)
plt.colorbar(im)
plt.show()
```

[image]

However, if you don't already have a gradient in the list of colors (as the above does not) then it might be more useful to use a [`matplotlib.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap.html#matplotlib.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap) instead. This is a bit more tricky because of the format expected,

> [...] `segmentdata` argument is a dictionary with a set of red, green and blue entries. Each entry should be a list of *x*, *y0*, *y1* tuples, forming rows in a table [...].
>    Each row in the table for a given color is a sequence of *x*, *y0*, *y1* tuples. In each sequence, *x* must increase monotonically from 0 to 1. For any input value *z* falling between `x[i]` and `x[i+1]`, the output value of a given color will be linearly interpolated between `y1[i]` and `y0[i+1]`

Such a dictionary can be generated algorithmically by the method in the example below

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import LinearSegmentedColormap
from matplotlib import cm

# Tableau 20 color palette for demonstration
colors = [(31, 119, 180), (174, 199, 232), (255, 127, 14), (255, 187, 120)]
colors = [(e[0] / 255.0, e[1] / 255.0, e[2] / 255.0) for e in colors]

nc = len(colors)
c = np.zeros((3, nc, 3))
rgb = ['red', 'green', 'blue']
for idx, e in enumerate(colors):
    for ii in range(3):
        c[ii, idx, :] = [float(idx) / float(nc - 1), e[ii], e[ii]]

cdict = dict(zip(rgb, c))
cmap = LinearSegmentedColormap('tab20', cdict)

a = np.outer(np.linspace(0, 1, 20), np.linspace(0, 1, 20))
im = plt.imshow(a, cmap=cmap)
plt.colorbar(im)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Assuming the input list `colors` has the proper RGB format.